# Flex table header respecting width of the content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently all columns have the same width. I would like the first column with the "X" content to shrink to the width of the content inside it but without hard coding its width.

The header column that is empty should also respect the width of the content.

```css
.table__row{
  display: flex;
}

.table__column {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  
  <div class="table__row -header">
    <div class="table__column"></div>
    <div class="table__column">Day</div>
    <div class="table__column">Time</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="table__column">
      <a href="#">X</a>
    </div>
    <div class="table__column">Monday</div>
    <div class="table__column">12:00</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="table__column">
      <a href="#">X</a>
    </div>
    <div class="table__column">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="table__column">13:20</div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-grow: 0;` to the first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Basicly you need to set flex-grow to 0 for the elements in that "column".

```css
.table__row{
  display: flex;
}

.table__column {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.shrink {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  
  <div class="table__row -header">
    <div class="shrink table__column"></div>
    <div class="table__column">Day</div>
    <div class="table__column">Time</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="shrink table__column">
      <a href="#">X</a>
    </div>
    <div class="table__column">Monday</div>
    <div class="table__column">12:00</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="shrink table__column">
      <a href="#">X</a>
    </div>
    <div class="table__column">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="table__column">13:20</div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css

```
.-header .table__column:first-child{
  display: contents;
}

<div class="table">

  <div class="table__row -header">
    <div class=" table__column"></div>
    <div class="table__column">Day</div>
    <div class="table__column">Time</div>
  </div>

  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="shrink table__column">
      <a href="#">X</a>
    </div>
    <div class="table__column">Monday</div>
    <div class="table__column">12:00</div>
  </div>

  <div class="table__row">
    <div class="shrink table__column">
      <a href="#">X</a>
    </div>
    <div class="table__column">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="table__column">13:20</div>
  </div>


</div>
```

[image]